# Change subquery to join on two columns in Oracle view

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I am extending an existing view with 5 SELECTs (UNION-ed) that has a subquery in one of the WHERE clauses.

The table used in that subquery now needs to be accessed in all of the SELECT statements, so I want to JOIN it instead (after a bit of research right here :) ).

The current form is like this (simplified)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM 
    PERSON ,
    ADDRESS ,
    OWNER ,
    OBJECT
WHERE 
    PERSON.PERSONID = ADDRESS.PERSONID
    AND PERSON.PERSONID = OWNER.PERSONID (+)
    AND OWNER.OBJECTID = OBJECT.OBJECTID
    AND
    (
       OBJECT.REG_REQUIRED NOT in
       (
          'Y'
       )
       OR
       (
          OBJECT.REG_REQUIRED in ('Y')
          AND OWNER.PERSONID || OWNER.OBJECTID IN
          (
             SELECT
             REG.PERSONID || REG.OBJECTID
             FROM REGISTRATIONS REG
             WHERE APPROVED IN ('Y','V')
          )
       )
    )
```

The join needs to take into account the fact that there is a concatenation in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM 
    PERSON ,
    ADDRESS ,
    OWNER ,
    OBJECT ,
    REGISTRATIONS REG
WHERE 
    PERSON.PERSONID = ADDRESS.PERSONID
    AND PERSON.PERSONID = OWNER.PERSONID (+)
    AND OWNER.OBJECTID = OBJECT.OBJECTID
    AND 
    (
       OBJECT.REG_REQUIRED NOT in
       (
          'Y'
       )
       OR
       (
          OBJECT.REG_REQUIRED in ('Y')
          AND (( OWNER.PERSONID || OWNER.OBJECTID = REG.PERSONID || REG.OBJECTID ) AND REG.APPROVED IN ('Y','V'))
       )
    )
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I think the join can / should be separate from the rest of the subquery's condition like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM 
    PERSON ,
    ADDRESS ,
    OWNER ,
    OBJECT ,
    REGISTRATIONS REG
WHERE 
    PERSON.PERSONID = ADDRESS.PERSONID
    AND PERSON.PERSONID = OWNER.PERSONID (+)
    AND OWNER.OBJECTID = OBJECT.OBJECTID
    AND OWNER.OBJECTID = OBJECT.OBJECTID
    AND OWNER.PERSONID || OWNER.OBJECTID = REG.PERSONID (+) || REG.OBJECTID (+)
    AND
    (
       OBJECT.REG_REQUIRED NOT in
       (
          'Y'
       )
       OR
       (
          REG.APPROVED IN ('Y','V'))
       )
    )
```